# hey I got a problem regarding git and heroku

Tags: reactjs, git, github, heroku

Hej guys,

I am having a huge problem regarding heroku and github. I am new regarding github and maybe there is something I do not see at the moment but it drives me crazy.

Technically speaking, the problem is that somehow even with my code changed, the website is not updating. I can see the changes on the localhost3000, but when I do git add . , commit and push nothing is happening. I would appreciate it if someone could help me understand what is happening.

Furthermore, I factory reset my laptop and updated on windows 11. When it comes to heroku log in the git stucks after the login is successful and I do not know if it is supposed to do that. Thank you in advance.

P.S. I will upload photos and more information if someone answers to me!

Sincerely,
Nikos

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Sure thanks Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only do you have to push your code to your repo, but you also need to push it to Heroku remote. It doesn't read directly from your repo. Run `git push heroku main`. This was found in the [Deploying Code](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git) section of the Heroku docs which may be of help to you.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I think I fixed it!